# Pre populate claim during sign up

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Is it possible to direct a user to a user flow along with a value that we want to set on a custom attribute? We dont want the user to be able to edit this field, it is ok if they see it.

I would like to have a custom app where the user will fill out some info, the app will validate their info against an internal database and return a value we would like to store in a custom attribute (an internal username).

I would then like to send the user off to a sign up user flow where they can either create a local account or create an account with an external IDP and the custom attribute would be pre populated for them and not editable.

Answer (score 0):

To pre-populate the claim, set it as an input field on the form.

To make it non-editable, copy it to a [readonly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimsschema#readonly) claim and display the readonly claim as an output.

To pass the data, make the whole flow a sign-up flow.

You can call a REST API in the flow to validate the data. Store the return value in an extension attribute.

Then ask the user if they want to federate with an external IDP.

If so, do the federation and add the value to the social account.

If not, create a local account and add the value.

You would have to create an external account beforehand.

Comment: The read only setting looks great. However how can I securely pass the value from my app to the signup policy/flow.

Comment: I had thought about calling a REST API from within the flow, I do this on another project. However the API to do the validation and return the internal username will not be publicly available to the B2C.

I was hoping to find some other way to pass the data to the sign up process.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out you can send back custom errors from a rest API. What I am ending up doing is gathering the data from the user, sending it to a custom API for validation, then if it validates properly, the API returns the custom attribute.

If the validation fails I can return errors to the B2C that will be shown on the sign up page.